# Posts active and expired in different loops

Tags: loop

I am in search of the best way to display pages active posts categories and expired after a certain period. I want to display active posts or have no expiration date in the main loop and those that expire in a loop below.

For this I used the plugin advanced custom field ( expiration ) which define the expiration date. With loops below, I get the result I want, however, would help to improve. For example, in the loop of expired posts, the H2 tag appears on the page even if there are no expired posts, and if I move it under the condition "if ( $ exhale < $ blogtime )", it appears in all expired posts, what do not want, I want to appear only once above all expired posts.

Another question I have is whether these loops will somehow require more work from the server, since it will have to make new appointments.

```
    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

        <?php if ( is_home() && ! is_front_page() ) : ?>
            <header>
                <h1 class="page-title screen-reader-text"><?php single_post_title(); ?></h1>
            </header>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php
        // Start the loop.
        while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        $blogtime = date( 'm/d/Y H:i:s', current_time( 'timestamp', 0 ) );
        $blogt = date( '0' );
        $expire = get_field('expiration');
            if( $expire > $blogtime ) {

            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() ); }

            elseif( $expire < $blogt ) {

            get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() ); }

        // End the loop.
        endwhile;

    endif;
    ?>

    <?php
    $args = array( 
        'post_type' => array('post','news'), 
        'posts_per_page' => 15, 
        'cat' => $cat,
        'meta_key'   => 'expiration',
        'orderby'    => 'meta_value_num',
        'order'      => 'DESC',
    );

        $eventloop = new WP_Query($args);
        if ( $eventloop->have_posts() ) : 

            echo '<h2>Expired</h2>';

            while ( $eventloop->have_posts() ) : $eventloop->the_post();
                $blogtime = date( 'm/d/Y H:i:s', current_time( 'timestamp', 0 ) );
                $blogt = date( '0' );
                $expire = get_field('expiration');


                    if( $expire < $blogtime ) {

                        if ( $expire > $blogt ) {

                    get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() ); 

                } }

            endwhile;
        endif;
    ?>
```

Comment: have a look at [`meta_query` arguments](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters). you can do the date comparison in the query rather than in the loop so you get back only posts that match. also see [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) if you want to alter the main query to add `meta_query` parameters.